# Get absolute base url in ASP.NET MVC without using Request or Context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I need to be able to request app endpoints without having access to `Request` or `Context` (I'm writing scheduling system, that will trigger some of app web api). How do I do that?

I know that I can get a virtual path with `System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath` if the app is deployed in IIS. This is fine with me.

I think I can also safely assume that I can access app by `localhost`

I need a port number and a protocol. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Out of interest, why don't you have access to `Request` and `Context`?

Comment: @Pieter As I mentioned, I need to execute on operation on schedule. During execution there is no `Request` or `Context` because there is no user connected and nobody sends a request. Many scheduling systems execute tasks in a separate process to be sure it can be executed no matter what IIS is doing right now

Comment: @Pieter Imagine a task being executed in the middle of the night when the last user has disconnected in the evening

Comment: Perhaps you could use [Microsoft.Web.Administration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=iis-dotnet)

Comment: @JeremyThompson This is a possible solution and I have investigated that before a bit. This requires to install additional component to IIS and I'm not sure does this require elevated permissions (it probably does as this allow me to manage all IIS, not just my configuration)

Comment: Have you tried `IHttpContextAccessor`?

Comment: @Pieter I had no idea about this interface, but doesn't seem to apply to me. 1. I'm not use asp core. 2. In my case the problem is not that the context is somewhere but I do not have access to it, the problem is that there is no context at all, as the executing code is not initiated by the Request, but rather by the scheduler. Imagine a separate thread running in the background of asp application, that is firing a method once per hour

Comment: For now the solution for me is to save the url when I initialize the task in scheduler (during this process I have Request). The url is saved in the database, so it can be restored even if server is restarted. This has some drawbacks, but this works for me. I'm still interested in the proper solution

Comment: @Archeg Apologies, my understanding was that this interface was for accessing the context whilst there is no request.  I must have misunderstood it.  I saw it mentioned  and it reminded me of your situation.

Comment: @Pieter No need to apologize, you've tried to help, and this is useful to know anyway no matter that I can't use it in particularly this situation. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Add key in web.config

```
<add key="localurl" value="http://localhost:8080" />
```

Then call the value like this

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("localurl")
```

Comment: This would require extra work to fill in this value every time. Unfortunately for us this will not work as we deploy too often to various servers with various configurations, although in general this is I guess a viable option